# Calculating derivatives for matrix/vector products

Tags: matrices, derivatives

$$
\frac{\sum_{i\in\Omega} (\mathbf q_i-\alpha)^T A(\mathbf q_i-\alpha)}{\sum_{i\in\Omega}((\mathbf q_i-\alpha)^T(\mathbf q_i -\alpha))}
$$

What would be the derivative of the above equation with respect to $\alpha$?

$q, \alpha$: vectors,
A: matrix.

I tried calculating the derivative and I end up getting a zero in the numerator.

Would it be zero or have a numerator${}= \sum_i 2(A-1)(q_i-\alpha)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_k\}$ denote the standard basis vectors, and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
P &= \alpha{\tt1}^T
 \quad&\implies\quad Pe_k = \alpha \\
Q &= {\tt\large[}q_1\;q_2\;\ldots\,q_n{\tt\large]}
 \quad&\implies\quad Qe_k = q_k \\
R &= (P-Q)
 \quad&\implies\quad Re_k = \alpha-q_k \\
dR &= dP = d\alpha{\tt1}^T \\
}$$
Consider the following function of an arbitrary matrix $M$
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= \sum_{k\in\Omega} (q_k-\alpha)^TM(q_k-\alpha) \\
 &= \sum_{k\in\Omega} (Re_k)^TM(Re_k) \\
 &= \sum_{k\in\Omega} e_k^T(R^TMR)e_k \\
 &= \left(\sum_{k\in\Omega} e_ke_k^T\right):(R^TMR) \\
 &= \Phi :(R^TMR) \\
 &= M:R\Phi R^T \\
}$$
and its differential
$$\eqalign{
d\psi &= M:\big(dR\,\Phi R^T+R\Phi\,dR^T\big) \\
 &= \big(M+M^T\big):dR\,\Phi R^T \\
 &= \big(MR\Phi +M^TR\Phi \big):dR \\
}$$
where $\Phi$ is a diagonal matrix, with ones and zeros along the main diagonal. Depending on what $\Omega$ represents, I assume this could equal the identity matrix $I$ in some (most?) cases.

This function appears in the numerator
$\big(\nu = A:R\Phi R^T\big)$
and in the denominator
$\big(\delta = I:R\Phi R^T\big)$
of your function. So we need to calculate the gradient of their ratio.
$$\eqalign{
\rho &= \delta^{-1}\nu \\
d\rho &= \delta^{-1}d\nu - \nu\delta^{-2}d\delta \\
&= \delta^{-1}(AR\Phi+A^TR\Phi):dR - \nu\delta^{-2}(IR\Phi+I^TR\Phi):dR\\
 &= \delta^{-1}\Big(A+A^T - 2\rho I\Big)R\Phi:d\alpha{\tt1}^T \\
 &= \delta^{-1}\Big(A+A^T - 2\rho I\Big)R\Phi{\tt1}:d\alpha \\
 &= \delta^{-1}\Big(A+A^T - 2\rho I\Big)R\phi:d\alpha \\
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\alpha}
 &= \delta^{-1}\Big(A+A^T - 2\rho I\Big)R\phi \\
}$$
where $\phi$ is a vector whose elements equal either one or zero. It is the main diagonal of $\Phi$.